# Sorting an array by values first, then keys

Tags: php

I want to sort this key-value array by values first, then keys.

This is the array:

```
$a = [
    10 => 1,
    4 => 2,
    3 => 2
];
```

i want to get:

```
4 => 2,
3 => 2,
10 => 1
```

I tried to use `arsort`, but can't get current answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `uksort` to sort by keys, use those keys to look up the values in the array, do a comparison by values first and keys upon equality:

```
uksort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($arr) {
    if (($res = $arr[$a] - $arr[$b]) != 0) {
        return $res;
    }
    return $a - $b;
});
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/476 for more in-depth explanations of sort callbacks.

Comment: I tried `uksort`, but i did not pass the `$arr` to the inner function. Thankyou